# silent install : cant isntall FireFox silently with batch file

Tags: firefox, batch-file, silent-installer

I'm trying to execute silent installation of FF. 
in cmd the command "Firefox Setup X.exe" -ms works with no problems.
but when i'm trying to execute this command through bat file, it works, but the installation is not silent (some installation dialogs pop up...)

how it can be fixed ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could redirect it's output it to nul or a log file:

```
"Firefox Setup X.exe" -ms 1>nul

"Firefox Setup X.exe" -ms > ffinstall.log
```